# r emmeans interaction term with p values in rms::ols

Tags: r, lm, interaction, emmeans

When I fit a regular linear regression model using the `lm` function

```
library(emmeans)

data(mtcars)
head(mtcars)

mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

fit1 <- lm(mpg ~ hp + wt*cyl, data = mtcars)
```

I am able to estimate the EMM with p-values of the interaction term using the emmeans function as shown below

```
emm_fit1 <- emmeans(fit1, ~ wt*cyl)
summary(emm_fit1, infer = TRUE)


wt cyl emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 3.22 4     20.1 1.546 25     16.9     23.3  12.996  <.0001
 3.22 6     18.9 0.968 25     16.9     20.9  19.498  <.0001
 3.22 8     18.2 1.152 25     15.8     20.6  15.789  <.0001
```

I am curious to know what is the equivalent of `emmeans` for interaction term for model fit using `rms::ols` function

Comment: `wt` is a covariate, and by default it gets reduced toi its mean. You can use, e.g., `at = list(wt = 3:5)` to get separate estimates for different weights. Another matter is that really, your model fits trend lines for `wt` having different slopes for meach `cyl`. I suggest looking at `emtrends()` which can be used to estimate those slopes explicitly, and then `pairs()` on those results to compare the slopes.

Comment: PS I think `emmeans()` will work the same way for a model fitted with `rms::ols()`, however my sense is that the developer of **rms** would not approve of your doing so.